# Howto send notification from raspberry pi using curl

Tags: curl, raspberry-pi, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app that is receiving notifications via Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Sending notifications from the Firebase Console works fine but I want to send them from a Raspberry Pi using curl like this (found somewhere on stackoverflow):

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization:key=<api key>" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{\"to\" : \"<registration id>\", \"notification\" : {\"body\" : \"Yellow\"} \"priority\" : \"high\"}"
```

That allways givs me:

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Internal Server Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Internal Server Error</H1>
<H2>Error 500</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Added:
my registration id looks like this (almost):

> dxxxxxxxVEs:APA9xxxcL--JnhswC1w8utjxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxglosvLbvEAwh7sxxxxxxxxxQo3Fq4sn0yqZUN6Hy89IB9mAS3FusBo68UE4l3xDVRHxxxxxxxxxxpANAHWuLgXHqBoDsLsXBj

Comment: Have you looked in the server's error log file? The exact reason should be logged there.

Comment: @Pekka웃 server and her logs belongs to google ;-)

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn this line works for me. May be this is transient or has been fixed already? How does your <registration id> look like?

Comment: @fukanchik oh, ok. When used correctly, a 500 error is a pointer to problems on the server side, though - not with the request.

Comment: @fukanchik: still the same error ... definitely not a temporary problem ... added my registration id to the original question ... although is think the registration id is ok because it works when i use it in the firebase console ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma before priority high.

Can debug this by entering JSON into [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)

This can then be added to CURL like so:

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization:key=<api key>" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d '{"to": "<registration id>", "notification": {"body": "Yellow"},"priority": "high"}'
```

NOTE: The single quotes to avoid having to escape the double quotes.